# Space showing before image url in Wordpress while using WP Bakery

Tags: php, html, database, wordpress

We are using Wordpress with WP Bakery's Visual Composer. I am having a problem with images not showing up. Go to this page to see what I mean: http://inventivewebdesign.com/sierra-winds/our-products/shelters/

If I look at the code and go to the first broken image on the page it is pointing to https://inventivewebdesign.com/sierra-winds/wp-content/uploads/Shelter-Reno-NV-1.png which exists. The problem seems to be that there is a space or a %20 in front of the url.

Here is the code:

```
<img width="882" height="389" src=" https://inventivewebdesign.com/sierra-winds/wp-content/uploads/Shelter-Reno-NV-1.png" class="vc_single_image-img attachment-full" alt="Shelter Reno NV" srcset="%20https://inventivewebdesign.com/sierra-winds/wp-content/uploads/Shelter-Reno-NV-1.png 882w, %20https://inventivewebdesign.com/sierra-winds/wp-content/uploads/Shelter-Reno-NV-1-300x132.png 300w, %20https://inventivewebdesign.com/sierra-winds/wp-content/uploads/Shelter-Reno-NV-1-768x339.png 768w" sizes="(max-width: 882px) 100vw, 882px">
```

If I remove the %20 and the spaces the image shows up (using Inspect in Chrome). I have checked the database and there are no spaces in front of the urls in the GUID column of the Post table or anywhere else.

I have tried using Velvet blues to replace the URL with space in front of it and a %20 in front of it but it finds no matches. I even tried to replace https with http and back to https but it didn't work either.

Can anyone help me find out why this space and the %20 is showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0x20 is the ASCII character for space, so I think you should check your Wordpress settings for an extra space before the address, something like: " https://"

Check the Dashboard -> General Settings and make sure there are no spaces before the https in WordPress Address URL and Site Address URL.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, there were no spaces but I think that the hosting account changed the site to HTTPS and it didn't register in WP. Once I hit update in General Settings I had to login again and it works!

Comment: Glad to hear it's fixed. Migrating WP to https can sometimes have such unwanted side-effects.